# XCode: Where to put image resources

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add some `App Icons` and `Launch Images` for my App. My code-files are organized in groups inside Xcode and the same in the File System. I tried to drag a folder named `Resources` with my PNG images into my App and afterwards trying to add them as the `App Icons` and `Launch Images` for my App, but Xcode then gave me an warning and copied the file to the root of my project -- both in Xcode and File System.

Is it normal, that the Image are put in the root (in same level as the xcodeproj file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's OK. What can I suggest you is not to worry about filesystem and organize your files/directories within the project.

It's same as with iTunes: you don't care what and where your files are, but you have a nice interface to work with them.

Comment: I Think you are right, but it's not consistent that some image resources are put in the root with the xcodeproj file, and other in the project folder.

Comment: @DennisMadsen that was frustrating me to but with time I've taught myself to ignore the filesystem and have organized all the stuff within the project viewer.