# different backgrounds on different iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

**1.** What is the best way to insert a background in a xcode ios app?
**2.** I have two backgrounds, one big that covers it all and one smaller with some details on the bottom. Do i have to make two different pictures for the smaller background so that it fits on all iphones?

-Simon

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371315/xcode-where-to-put-image-resources

Comment: no its not, different problems

Comment: Have you tried to place them both inside their own image view and then adjust either the struts and springs (iOS 5) or the constraints (iOS 6)?  Also, do the two backgrounds overlap, or are they next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in general the best approach is to create two images that have the same content but are different in size.
You should create one image that is 320X480 for the iPhone 4 and below and one image that is 640X960 for the retina display on iPhone 4S and above. the format is:

ImageName.png (320X480)

ImageName@x2.png (640X960)

When you're referring to an image in your code you should use ImageName.png as the source image and the device will automatically decide whether to use the regular image or the retina display image.

It will be very user friendly (to say the least) to use the same content in your background whether it's an iPhone 4 and below or above.

As a side note: if you are using Cocos2d the HD image format changes to ImageName-hd.png

Answer (score 3):

The background picture should be on the main view and for inserting the smaller picture, use a subview. You can also popup a subview or animate it if u want to.